Select from table where a pair of columns matches one of any many pairs of values
I need to find all rows in a table where a pair of columns matches any entry from a list of pairs of values.  For instance, when looking for a single column, you would do
SELECT *
FROM Table t
WHERE t.column IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');

What I need is basically something like this:
SELECT *
FROM Table t
WHERE (t.column1, t.column2) IN
  (('value1', 1),
   ('value2', 2),
   ('value3', 3));

Note that I am not looking for this:
SELECT *
FROM Table t
WHERE 
   t.column1 IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
   AND t.column2 IN (1,2,3);

As that would give me all rows where column1 and columns2 match their lists independently of each other, as opposed to matching specific pairs.  The pair ('value1', 3) should not match my target query.
How can I accomplish this in SQL Server?

Concatenate column+column2 and mach 1 simple list

@BartMcEndree That would prevent the use of indexes, and would be incorrect in the case of abc,def matching ab,cdef

where col1 = v11 and col2 = v12 or col1 = v21 and col2 = v22 or col1 = v31 and col2 = v32

You can join a VALUES constructor
SELECT t.*
FROM Table t
JOIN (VALUES
   ('value1', 1),
   ('value2', 2),
   ('value3', 3)
) v(colum1, column2)
  ON v.column1 = t.column1
 AND v.column2 = t.column2;

You can also use a Table Value Parameter or a table variable or a temp table.
